# Should you obligate yourself in 2 days Purim

Tags: halacha, purim, shushan-purim

If you are in TelAviv all day 14 (24hrs), and Jerusalem all day 15th (24hrs), simple halacha is you are obligated in both days.  Even if just lechumra, because the Rosh says you are only obligated on the 14th.  There is plenty of discourse on this.

But do any of the Poskim say if you should or should not do this?  Is it a good idea? Or a bad thing to do?  I remember seeing some poskim say you should not try to double your obligation but cant find them now.

Any qualitative halacha out there?

Comment: I wonder what Yeshaya Leibowitz would say to this question ....